# The git commands are not running in the function when I run the powershell file?

Tags: git, powershell, cmd, scripting, command

When I change the files in the directory the changes are monitored and logged but the git commands are not working in the powershell script.

```
$filewatcher.Path =$args
write-host $filewatcher.Path
$filewatcher.Filter = "*.*"
$filewatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$filewatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true   

$writeaction = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                Add-content "D:\FileWatcher_log.txt" -value $logline
              }    

$pushaction = {
                write-host $filewatcher.Path
                $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
                $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
                $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
                write-host $logline
                git -C $filewatcher.Path add .
                git -C $filewatcher.Path commit -m $logline
                git -C $filewatcher.Path push
             }

Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Created" -Action $pushaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Changed" -Action $pushaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Deleted" -Action $pushaction
Register-ObjectEvent $filewatcher "Renamed" -Action $pushaction
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

**The output on shell looks like-:**

```
 C:\Users\ABHIJEET>PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -command "C:\users\abhijeet\desktop\test\backup-win.ps1"  C:\Users\Abhijeet\Desktop\test\
    C:\Users\Abhijeet\Desktop\test\
    
    Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location             Command
    --     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------             -------
    1      8eb075d3-923...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
    2      bb594e1a-742...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
    3      ae2a4956-ca2...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
    4      4241104d-994...                 NotStarted    False                                ...
    
    04/01/2021 17:36:38, Created, C:\Users\Abhijeet\Desktop\test\New Text Document.txt
    
    04/01/2021 17:36:43, Renamed, C:\Users\Abhijeet\Desktop\test\file2.txt
```

**The git commands are not running.**

Comment: @RafsanJany Because bash scripting is a course in misery.

Comment: Try debugging your issue more thoroughly: for example, add `git -C ...Path status` (or `git status -sb`, which will be more compact) between your git actions

Comment: @RafsanJany i need to set up watcher in windows that needs .NET and powershell

Comment: @LeGEC the git commands are straightup ignored even the status one